# not able to fetch code using Powershell from Git Organisation. Getting Must authenticate to access this API

Tags: git, powershell

Please tell me how i get the scripts stored under Organistaion repository.
I am getting `Must authenticate to access this API` error:

```
$GithubCredentials = (Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter the Github User credentials')
$githubusername = $GithubCredentials.UserName
$githubpassword = $GithubCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$AuthString = "{0}:{1}" -f $githubusername,$githubpassword
$AuthBytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetBytes($AuthString)
$global:BasicCreds = [Convert]::ToBase64String($AuthBytes)
$headers= @{
    Authorization = 'Basic {0}' -f $BasicCreds;
    "Accept" = "application/vnd.github.v3.raw";
};
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$GitHubUri = "https://alm-github.systems.test.com/api/v3/repos/test"
$data1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $GitHubUri -Headers $headers -Method Get -Verbose
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the cause of your problem but GitHub is deprecating authentication by user/password for Apis: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-username-and-password You'd better generate a token and use it...

Comment: Ok. That's not the problem because it seems you use your GitHub Enterprise instance...

Comment: this is working now with public repo. after i changed the repo to private its not working.